# Panel vs. cross-section: different impact of a variable

Tags: regression, time-series, regression-coefficients, confounding, cross-section

I study the composition of the labor force, which consists of two groups of workers in a particular industry, full-time and part-time employees. I have data for two years, and each year I observe a negative impact of alternative employment opportunities (that is, the number of jobs in other industries) on the ratio of full-time workers to all. However, when I combine my data into a panel, I see a positive relationship. This makes more sense, as when there are many other opportunities, employers would be motivated to hire people full-time to ensure their availability. But why this does not show up in a cross-section? Looks like a puzzle to me. Do you have any ideas?